# Getting data from local running java app to google cloud app and back

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I wanted to dive into the world of distributed systems, cloud computing, IoT, etc., and I gotta be honest, I imagined everything being a little more intuitive than it finally turned out.
I had a tiny testing architecture in mind, that I'd like to set up with Google Clouds and their services, but I am kinda stuck since I can't get my head around some concepts.

What I basically wanted to do (as a first step) is writing a simple java application that would run locally on my computer. This application should just generate random numbers and send those numbers somehow to the google cloud. On the cloud I wanted to define another java application that would manipulate those random numbers in some kind of way (it doesn't matter actually). Afterwards, the output should somehow get back to me of course. And actually, at the moment, I don't even care about how exactly. It could be somehow back to my local app (with some kind of listener, would that be possible?). But it could also simply store the results somewhere on the google cloud? Or maybe upload them to my google drive?

I guess you already noticed that - at some points - I don't even know what i want exactly, since I'm not sure of what is possible, and what not.

Could you provide me some help to get this set up?
The most important questions for me right now are:

- Do I need to use a pubsub system, where my generated numbers are sent
  to, and which then forwards this to the cloud app, that transforms my
  data?
- How do I get my data from the local app to the cloud services?
- Would my data transforming app run on Google Dataflow?
- Above I wrote "as a first step"... because later I would also like to send config files (for example in json format, or xml) to the cloud, and the
  cloud application should transform those config files... if I get the
  first scenario running the I guess this woul also be no problem
  right?

Those are just a few of the questions that are on my mind currently. The most important ones I guess.

It would be a big help. Sorry, if the questions are not very precise, but I really need some kind of pointing into the right direction.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be good to read up on some of the technologies you mention here:

- [**Google Cloud Pubsub**](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview): Pub/Sub enables you to publish messages to a topic, and consume them in another place in the (Google) Cloud. You can see some different examples of publishers and consumers in the link. In your case you could for example write a Java application that writes random numbers to the Pub/Sub queue, where they will sit for 7 days to be consumed by another component (for example, Google Cloud Dataflow). To get started developing, you can find the SDKs [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries) (there is a Java SDK).
- [**Google Cloud Dataflow**](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) is managed service running [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/) pipelines to process your data at scale. You can learn about the different concepts [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/programming-model) and get started designing your pipeline [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/programming-model). I suggest taking a look at some examples first though, which will make it more easy to grasp what is actually going on. Dataflow has a PubSub connector, so in your application you will be able to read from the topic you created before. In Dataflow you can for example multiply all your random numbers and write them to a certain sink (for example Google Cloud Storage, or even BigQuery or PubSub again).
- [**Google Cloud Storage**](https://cloud.google.com/storage/): is a cloud storage where you can put files, for example the output of your Dataflow pipeline. You will be able to manually download the files using the Cloud Console UI, or you can use one of the [SDKs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) to download the output programmatically.

Hope this gives you an overview and some pointers to start. Whenever you are ready and have a more concrete use case in mind, you can start looking at some more components.